# Find the period of sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, periodic-functions

A sequence is such that its terms are generated by the formula:
$$r_i =(ar_{i-1}+b\pmod m)$$

where $a,b,m,r_0$ are given.

find the period,that is the number of terms that are repeated.

For example, if $a = 2, b = 6, m = 12, r_0 = 11$, the generated sequence will be: $4, 2, 10, 2, 10, 2, 10, 2, 10, 2, 10$, ...

period of this is 2 because 2,10 are repeating

how to find the period?

Comment: Does the "%" mean remainder?

Comment: That was my guess when I edited it, @martycohen. In programming languages, $a%b$ is a little more complicated than $a\pmod b$, since it can be negative if $a$ is negative in some programming languages.

Comment: For $n>0$, $r_n = (\frac{a^n-1}{a-1}b + a^nr_0\mod m)$

Comment: A recipe is as follows. First determine the period modulo all prime power factors $p^\ell$ of $m$, and then apply the Chinese remainder theorem. Except for a few trivial degenerate cases the period will be equal to the order of $a$ modulo $p^\ell$. Exceptions are: trivial seed(s), the case where $p\mid a$, when the eventual period modulo $p^\ell$ will have length one, and the cases $a\equiv1\pmod p$, where you need extra factor(s) of $p$. At the CRT step you are to calculate the LCM of the mod $p^\ell$ lengths of the periods.